# C++ Compilar varios archivos - tasks.json

Tags: c++, json

Estoy tratando de compilar varios archivos usando VS Code, en Ubuntu. Tengo los siguientes.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clase.h"

int main(){
    mensaje miMensaje;
    miMensaje.imprimir();

    return 0;
}
```

funcion.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clase.h"
using namespace std;


void mensaje::imprimir() const{
    cout << "Mensaje de prueba" << endl;
}
```

clase.h

```
#include <iostream>

class mensaje{
    public:
        void imprimir() const;
};
```

Usando por consola el comando g++ main.cpp funcion.cpp -o main, funciona perfecto. El problema es al querer compilarlo en VSCode, que me devuelve el mensaje "referencia a `main' sin definir"

Asumo que es un problema en el archivo tasks.json. Por lo que vi, en ningún momento le paso el archivo funcion.cpp, pero probé de diferentes formas modificando el archivo, pero no logro hacer que compile.

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

después de mucho probar, encontré como poder hacerlo.

Hay que modificar el archivo tasks.json en las siguientes lineas, donde se pasan los diferentes argumentos:

```
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "${workspaceFolder}/funcion.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ]
```

Como tengo todos los archivos en la misma carpeta, las diferentes variables son:
${file} - El archivo actual, en mi caso main.cpp
${workspaceFolder} - La carpeta donde esta el proyecto, seguido del nombre del 2do archivo a compilar (Hay que agregar mas lineas similares en el caso de mas archivos).

Espero que sirva, gracias.